# Show only the most recent records and if they include a certain value

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to do the following:

In access, I have a table like this:

***customer table:***

[image]

And i´m trying to query the only the records with the most recent date, and if they have a value of 0.00EUR. If not, i don't want them to be displayed in the query.

Can anyone share some information on how this can be achieved?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by most recent date? Only top date having value `0.00EUR`?

Comment: Please modify your question to include which records shown you expect to be returned in your query.

Comment: Sorry for my english. But yes, i believe that's it. I'm trying to obtain only the costumers that currently have a top date with a value of 0.00EUR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tblCustomer
WHERE ValueEUR = 0 AND DateTime = 
    (Select Max(DateTime)
    From tblCustomer As T
    Where T.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID)
```

Comment: Yes, that was what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, but it didn't quite help. It works, but only shows the most recent record with a value of 0. I think the problem is that i´m not explaining myself right.

Comment: You are very clear: _only the records with the most recent date, and if they have a value of 0.00EUR._

Comment: If a costumer latest transaction wasn't one with a 0 value i dont want it to show in the query. I'm trying to obtain only the records where the latest transaction of a costumer has a value of 0.

Comment: Gustav, thank you so much!!! It worked! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Gustav Good solution.

Comment: @Gustav, once again thank you so much about the solution you provided! It does exactly what I was trying to do. I just wanted to understand exactly how this is done. Can you tell me what `From tblCustomer As T
    Where T.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID)` is actually doing? I can´t understand what the "T" is or referes to. Thank you so much, once again.

Comment: **T** is an alias for the table to distinguish between the two "instances" of the table.

Comment: @Gustav, again, thank you so much for the solution provided. Has been working greatly. But now I'm facing an issue. My number of records is massive, the table I'm analysing ha s over 90.000 thousand records. And when I run the query that you so kindly provided. Access simply can't digest all the info. It takes forever, or even, stops working. Any ideia on how to get around this? Thank you so much in advance. Stay safe.

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation for this simple technique. You may have to create a _temp table_ filled with the `Max([DateTime])` for each customer, then use this table in place of the subquery. This query you may morf to a traditional select query with an _inner join_ between the two tables. Finally, if many `ValeurEUR` are _not zero_, you may replace the table with a select query filtering on `ValueEUR = 0`. Also, limit the temp table by excluding these.

Comment: Done it! :D Thanks @Gustav. Got it done! Thank you so much once again. Take care and stay safe. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think simple `SELECT` query should work for you. Try below query.

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer
WHERE ValueEUR=0 ORDER BY DateTime DESC;
```

[image]

***Query result:***
[image]